# spi-bcm2835 fe204000.spi: could not get clk: -517

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu Server 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4 8GB and shut it down normally yesterday it just says this error on screen when starting the kernel `spi-bcm2835 fe204000.spi: could not get clk: -517`.

I'm just running it as a NAS with samba.

Is there a way to get the Pi back up running or do I need to just flash the SD-Card again?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem until I decided to try a different power adapter. As soon as I plugged the pi in with a new power adapter, it booted perfectly fine. You might also want to try a new USB C cable.